# "Unknown type name 'tls_protocol_version_t' on the class NSURLSession"

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode11

In Xcode 11 the compiler show me "Unknown type name 'tls_protocol_version_t' on the class NSURLSession", i already tried deleting deriving data, cleaning and compiling, it's work fine in xcode 10, but not with 11. It seems very rare because is a class of Foundation.
What should i do?
[This is what happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQufX.jpg)

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: unfortunately is not my code, the error is on NSURLSession.h under Foundation framework